# C++ Builder - managing project group files

Tags: c++, dll, c++builder

I have a project group in C++ Builder containing VCL application (EXE) and few DLL projects. All projects in group have their own debug/release folders and when performing static dll linking I need .lib and .dll files of my dll projects copied into debug/release folder of the app using it. I would need this to be automatic after any of dll's compile. How to do it? Also, I need to make sure that all dll projects in group compile in specific order..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> All projects in group have their own debug/release folders and when performing static dll linking I need .lib and .dll files of my dll projects copied into debug/release folder of the app using it. I would need this to be automatic after any of dll's compile. How to do it?

Each project can have its own [output folder](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Paths_and_Directories_(C%2B%2B)) specified in the Project Options. You could simply make each DLL project output its compiled files to the same release/debug folders that the EXE project outputs to.

Alternatively, you can let each project continue to output to its own release/debug folders, and then use a [Post-Build Event](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Build_Events) to copy the compiled files to the EXE project's release/debug folders.

> Also, I need to make sure that all dll projects in group compile in specific order..?

Projects are compiled in the order they are listed in the project group, unless you select to compile specific projects individually, or select a project and choose the "Compile all from Here" option in the Project Manager.  If necessary, you can configure [project dependencies](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Project_Dependencies), so that compiling any given project will first compile any other projects it depends on.  For instance, the EXE project can depend on the DLL projects, then compiling the EXE will automatically compile the DLLs first.  If a given DLL project requires another DLL project to be compile first, configure that dependency accordingly.